# Extending Swift's Dictionary to conform to Protocol that requires the use of subscript causes Linker Error

Tags: swift, generics, linker, nsdictionary, protocols

The title says it all, but I have a protocol like:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    typealias KeyType
    typealias ValueType

    subscript(key: KeyType) -> ValueType? { get set }
}
```

And trying to make `Dictionary` conform to `MyProtocol` like:

```
extension Dictionary: MyProtocol {
}
```

results in the Linker Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"__TFVSs10Dictionarym9subscriptFQ_GSqQ0__", referenced from:
  __TTWUSs8Hashable___GVSs10DictionaryQ_Q0__18ProjectName11MyProtocolS1_FS2_m9subscriptFQQPS2_12KeyTypeGSqQS3_15ValueType_ in Searcher.o
```

Now, the interesting part is that if I reimplement subscript, the error goes away, but I don't know how to reimplement it without causing infinite recursion.

If instead of `{ get set }`, the protocol requires `{ get }` the error also goes away and the extension works as desired.

So I imagine the issue must be in the `set` side of things, trying to require `{ get mutating set }` also doesn't work.

Does anyone know **(a)** what's going on and **(b)** how to make `Dictionary` conform to `MyProtocol`, without having to resort to drastic solutions like reimplementing `subscript`?

At first I was convinced it was a bug with Swift, but after probing it a bit, I am not so sure.

I'm using Swift 1.2

**Edit:** I managed to make it work by doing the following:

```
extension Dictionary: MyProtocol {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            let index = self.indexForKey(key)

            if let i = index {
                return self[i].1
            }

            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                self.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
            } else {
                self.removeValueForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But re-implementing the Dictionary's subscript really doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

**Edit 2:** Clearer Question.

**Edit 3:** Tried the same code out in Swift 2.0 and it still doesn't work. Curiously the linker error is different this time:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift.Dictionary.subscript.materializeForSet : (A) -> B?", referenced from:
      protocol witness for _Test.MyProtocol.subscript.materializeForSet : (A.KeyType) -> A.ValueType? in conformance <A, B where A: Swift.Hashable> [A : B] : _Test.MyProtocol in _Test in TestFile.o
```

Comment: What problem are we actually trying to solve here?

Comment: How to make `Dictionary` conform to the protocol without having to reimplement core functionality like `subscript` of `Key -> Value`

Comment: I mean, why isn't Swift's default implementation of `subscript` enough to satisfy `MyProtocol`?

Comment: I don't have an answer or solution (and it *might* be a compiler bug), but interestingly it compiles if the protocol requests a *read-only* subscript: `subscript(key: KeyType) -> ValueType? { get }`.

Comment: What I'm asking is why you need to make up this protocol and make Dictionary conform to it, when you already know that Dictionary does have subscripting. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: @matt don’t know if this is the OP’s intent but one reason I can think of is to tag multiple dictionary-like containers (say you also had a red-black-tree-based map) with a key-subscripting protocol so you can write generically across them.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Obviously, but I'm trying to get the OP to _enunciate_ that goal so that we can discuss _that_.

Comment: I'm trying to create a caching system that accepts multiple caching strategies. The Protocol sets the contract for what's expected of a Cache. And having Dictionary conform to the Protocol gives me a simple Cache for free.

Comment: As a workaround you could just wrap the Dictionary in something else, surely.

Comment: Yes, I could work around it... But that's not the issue. The issue is why doesn't this work when, Dictionary clearly has a read-write subscript. Not only that, the Type Checker accepts Dictionary as a valid Cache, but I still get the Linker Error. Maybe this is not the place to ask it, then. But I was more interested in the Why this is happening than making my code work.

Comment: Well, the Swift compiler/linker is kind of buggy/quirky. This sort of thing happens a lot. Did you try it with Swift 2.0? I'm finding a lot of stuff has been fixed there (didn't try your code, sorry), plus there are some new language features that might prove useful.

Comment: Hadn't tried it in Swift 2.0, because it didn't really apply to the current problem. But the problem is still present there but the error is different, more detailed.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue while trying to define a general purpose `MapType` protocol that I can then implement for other types that are similar to `Dictionary` (e.g- tree-based maps). Similar to the OP my only workaround has been to add the mutating `removeValueForKey()` and `updateValue(forKey:)` methods and only define a read-only subscript, which means I can edit contents only via methods or type-specific subscripts, which is do-able, but not perfect.